# Handle date in the insertion, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

My question is simple how to insert a date in my Schema that will be 1 year from the present date ?

```
 const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

     User_id: {
           type: String,
           required:true
        },
     inscription_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
           } 
     end_inscription_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: xxxxx  // => Date.now + 1 year
           } 

});
```

For example:

Submit inscription 2019/07/24, the end date must be 2020/07/24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to calculate the one year later date and use that as your default value.

Try this :

```
var oneYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var oneYearLater = function() { return new Date(Date.now() + oneYear);};
```

Use function `oneYearLater` in your schema.

```
 const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

     User_id: {
           type: String,
           required:true
        },
     inscription_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
           } 
     end_inscription_date: {
            type: Date,
            default:  oneYearLater// => Date.now + 1 year
           } 

});
```

Or simply try to add the milli seconds in `Date.now`.

```
end_inscription_date: {
    type: Date,
    default:  Date.now() + 365*24*60*60*1000
}
```